# What distribution function do I get after squaring normal data?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

If I have some numbers that are drawn from a Gaussian distribution and then I square each of them, what distribution function will now describe my data?

---

Thank you Arthur. And what if I start with a lognormal distribution instead of a Gaussian? What would I get after squaring in that case?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution with $k=1$.

Comment: Thank you. And I see there is also a lambda parameter. What should I select for that?

Comment: For $k = 1$, $\lambda$ is simply the square of the mean of the Gaussian variable, according to the article I linked.